# In Swift, how to detect if a view controller is "from" a different view controller of a specific class

Tags: ios, swift3

I'm using Swift 3 in Xcode 8.3.3.

I have 2 view controllers, `A` and `B` that inherit from a regular `UIViewController` like this:

```
class A: UIViewController {}
class B: UIViewController {}
```

These 2 view controllers can be presented by a base view controller in a `UINavigationController`.

I have a different view controller, `Test`, which will eventually be presented by either `A` or `B`, meaning somewhere at the end of the hierarchy like this:

`Base` -> `A` or `B` -> `Other` -> `Other` -> `Test`

`Test` will present it's data differently depending on which one it came from.

I have an extension on `UIViewController` that provides a way of checking this, and it works just fine when I hardcode it for `A` and `B`:

```
extension UIViewController {
    var isFromA: Bool {
        if let nc = parent as? UINavigationController {
            return nc.viewControllers.filter({ ($0 as? A) != nil }).count > 0
        } else {
            if let _ = parent as? A {
                return true
            } else if parent != nil {
                return parent!.isFromA
            } else {
                return false
            }
        }
    }

    var isFromB: Bool {
        if let nc = parent as? UINavigationController {
            return nc.viewControllers.filter({ ($0 as? B) != nil }).count > 0
        } else {
            if let _ = parent as? B {
                return true
            } else if parent != nil {
                return parent!.isFromB
            } else {
                return false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the `Test` lifecycle code, I can use it like this:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    if isFromA {
        // do something
    } else if isFromB {
        // do something else
    }
}
```

So now I'm going to be adding a new view controller, `C`, which can also eventually present a `Test`. I don't want to just copy and paste the code again when I make the `isFromC` var. I want to make a helper function that takes an instance of a type of class to use in those `as?` checks. The new code would look something like this:

```
extension UIViewController {
    var isFromA: Bool {
        return isFrom(A)
    }

    var isFromB: Bool {
        return isFrom(B)
    }

    var isFromC: Bool {
        return isFrom(C)
    }

    fileprivate func isFrom(_ viewControllerClass: UIViewController) -> Bool {
        if let nc = parent as? UINavigationController {
            return nc.viewControllers.filter({ ($0 as? viewControllerClass) != nil }).count > 0
        } else {
            if let _ = parent as? viewControllerClass {
                return true
            } else if parent != nil {
                return parent!.isFrom(viewControllerClass)
            } else {
                return false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This doesn't compile, and it's not quite right anyways, because I don't have an actual instance of `A`, `B`, or `C` to pass into this helper function.

So what's the best way to solve this? Also note that I'm open to suggestions on reworking the helper function code as well, as I'm not sure if it covers all the combinations of navigation controllers and such.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way to pass a type as a parameter, after doing some searching. But the examples I was seeing didn't specifically cover my context (detecting if the currently presented view controller is downstream of another type of view controller in some way), so I decided to pose the question anyway, and provide my own answer. I'm still interested in any changes to the helper function, though.

But here's my solution:

```
extension UIViewController {
    var isFromA: Bool {
        return isFrom(viewControllerClassType: A.self)
    }

    var isFromB: Bool {
        return isFrom(viewControllerClassType: B.self)
    }

    var isFromC: Bool {
        return isFrom(viewControllerClassType: C.self)
    }

    fileprivate func isFrom(viewControllerClassType type: UIViewController.Type) -> Bool {
        if let nc = parent as? UINavigationController {
            return nc.viewControllers.filter({ $0.isKind(of: type) }).count > 0
        } else {
            if let _ = parent?.isKind(of: type) {
                return true
            } else if parent != nil {
                return parent!.isFrom(viewControllerClassType: type)
            } else {
                return false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know if using `UIViewController.Type` is the best way to go, but it does the job.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify what you have just a bit to use a generic type in your function and call it instead of your computed vars.

```
extension UIViewController {

    func isFrom<T>(viewControllerClass: T) -> Bool {
        guard let parent = parent else { return false }

        if let nav = parent as? UINavigationController {
            return nav.viewControllers.filter({ type(of: $0).self is T }).count > 0
        } else {
            if parent is T {
                return true
            } else {
                return parent.isFrom(viewControllerClass: viewControllerClass)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then call it with

```
if vc.isFrom(viewControllerClass: ClassA.self) {
    // do something
} else if vc.isFrom(viewControllerClass: ClassB.self) {
    // do something
}
```

That at least removes the need to add a new var for every parent class type.

Comment: Sure, that makes it a generic function instead, but otherwise not much different. I don't NEED the var with the current implementation either, I just prefer it. I don't need to mark the helper as fileprivate. But I do like the improvement to the helper function in terms of the `guard` statement.